# Is it possible to make a webview inside webpage?

Tags: html, rest, web

I have got regular webpage with url one. Is there a way to make a window inside it that will open URL two?
So the user will be on URL one but part of the page will show content of URL two?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't `<iframe>` what you are looking for?

Comment: yes thank you! I am just learning web it is what i am looking for